# TypeScript: Combine objects of an array to make a specific JSON

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am looping through an array of objects and I am trying to combine them to a specific JSON:

The array of objects:

```
[
    {
    'code': 'LA',
    'name': 'Local administrator',
    'id': 1
    },
    
    {
    'code': 'SA',
    'name': 'System administrator',
    'id': 2
    }
]
```

How can I combine them and have something like this?

```
[
   {
      "role":{
         "code":"LA",
         "name":"Local administrator",
         "id":1
      }
   },
   {
      "role":{
         "code":"SA",
         "name":"System administrator",
         "id":2
      }
   }
]
```

I am trying here if you like to help please fork this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2&ssl=41&ssc=2&pln=26&pc=1#code/AQGwpgLsCGBOvQJ7ALzANoG8CwAoYBA5AMYD2AJmIQFzCEAyAgoQDR4F0B20AtlbQ1LFoIGOR4BLThIDOEBBFKxW7IhPI1gARnYBfFsBz4iZSpsIBlZm2Nde-OhcRywPMZOlyFSlbcLrNACY9AF0Abjx2cCgIVwAHC2gANzBGeCRaaE5kNExdCPxo4FieOIAlUnAZTOzUDHDI-DgERAA6ADMlAFFoYgALAApyaAhoVAA+Q1Vi+IqquvRWpZLyyrAZA2HRhvxdAEoC9hXElLSW9EJYNcIQuqMOJdaVufW9AuAyThk11pBSAHMBsdkql0ogDo0APQAKmAfVIAHcPllgABJYD-SDFPpgYCdEB-BFSf7AWDrACuIAgAH5gNDIXgYY10NN7hwCAAiK7gDnUNnsjgc0xgXkcpgcmwC9kc7h8UX0IQidxSWTyEZKCXTKUc9S8nS2Di6ab6VlaznckV8s3S4Wiqyag0CmX2O3OErKzxqxSwB1SwW66jBR3AI22UMhRr0oA

Comment: So you just want to wrap the object in another object under a `role` property?

Comment: Yes and in fact there are more nested array of objects I would have to also found out how to add later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map over each array, returning a new object for each element:

```js
array.map((role) => ({ role }));
```

`({ role })` is short for `({ role: role })`. There are parentheses so that the object literal is not confused for the body of the arrow function.

```js
let array = [{
   'code': 'LA',
   'name': 'Local administrator',
   'id': 1
 }, {
   'code': 'SA',
   'name': 'System administrator',
   'id': 2
 }];

console.log(array.map((role) => ({ role })));
```